# How can I add other text/characters to a MySQL query (://, <,=, etc.)?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add things to a MySQL query (://, <,=, etc.)? I'm trying to use the following code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("----------","---------","--------");
    if (!$con) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $add_something = "<a href='http://google.com'>Click Here</a>";
    mysql_select_db("user_live", $con);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_new_post (user_full_name, user_new_post, user_username, user_date_post)
        VALUES ('Peter Allport', 'Check ittt outtt:" . $add_something  . "', 'peteca', '" . date("mjYgi") . "')");

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: .mysql_real_escape_string($add_something).

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: FYI: Your problem is not the `://` or `<` or `=`. None of these will cause errors. The issue is with quotes `'`. As others already said, `mysql_real_escape_string` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, escape with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_new_post (user_full_name, user_new_post, user_username, user_date_post)
VALUES ('Peter Allport', 'Check ittt outtt:" . mysql_real_escape_string($add_something)  . "', 'peteca', '" . date("mjYgi") . "')");
```

Even better, used parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
.mysql_real_escape_string($add_something).
```